# What is the best templating system to use with AmpersandJS?

Tags: ampersand.js

"What's the latest thinking on the best templating system to use with AmpersandJS - I don't love Jade and right now we're using some crap homebrew system which I want to change. Any thoughts, examples, experiences on this?" - @tkaria, AmpersandJS Gitter

Comment: An unqualified "best" solicits opinions. You "should use" whatever is well-suited to the requirements and scope defined, preference notwithstanding.

Comment: the question is a copy from the thread at https://gitter.im/AmpersandJS/AmpersandJS, also the question directly **asks for** opinion. Maybe swap "best" for "best convention"?

Answer (score 0):

You (probably really by now) should use ES6 Template literals.  Here's an example:

myTemplate.js

```
const template = context => {
    return `
        <div>My template ${context.myValue}</div>
    `;
};

export default template;
```

myView.js

```
import View from 'ampersand-view';
import MyTemplate from './myTemplate';

export default View.extend({
    template: MyTemplate
    // ...
});
```

Comment: While an option, this is largely a subjective choice.

Comment: I take your point, but from my view I would strongly disagree that you need to use a library in place of pure JavaScript which now supports this facility.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the examples use handlebars, but they are a few years old.

To future proof your app, you could use template literal. You need to be aware that not all browsers support template literals. (Internet Explorer does not support them). If you want to use template literals and maintain support with older browsers, you will need to use some type of transform/polyfill in your build scripts (transpile the es2016 to es5).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

One of ampersands main features is data-binding, so you don't really need a templating engine, you could even use string literals (just watch out for the whitespace).

Ampersand is very flexible, I would choose whatever templating engine you are most comfortable with.

Comment: if you use ES6 anything, you certainly should be transpiling code using Babel or a like to mitigate the issue that Rick points out